# Laravel 5.6 cache folder filling up

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a laravel 5.6 application which is incredibly simple it just has a few api methods which retrieve values from the database and return them but it does get quite a lot of traffic because the API methods get called on various pages of a high traffic site. The cache driver is set to file but I have not written any code that explicitly uses the cache.

However for some reason my /storage/framework/cache/data folder keeps filling up with loads and loads of folders with 2 bit hexadecimal names e.g 00, 03, 5b...

As soon as I clear the folder out within 30 seconds 50 or more have been created again. Does laravel cache certain things by default? Are these session ids or something? If I look inside one it will contain more hexadecimal named folders and if I look in one of them there will be a file with a random long name and no file extension and the contents of that file will be something like 1542892151i:1542892151;

Comment: Could it be that session data is stored within that folder?

Comment: The session driver is set to file as well but the directory is set to /storage/framework/sessions and there are 7 files in there. So I wouldn't expect session data to be stored in the cache folder but even if it was the amount of data getting stored seems to be significantly higher than the amount of sessions